# didEnterBackground in Kobold2d

Tags: kobold2d

In Cocos2d I would implement - `(void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application` inside of the AppDelegate, but in Kobold2d (I haven't worked with it much) that is all handled by `config.lua`, which is great, but how do I handle these `exit`/`enter`/`background` state changes of the application?

Do I have to to override something, or is there some specific place? I'm not sure what the best practice is here and either I am having a lot of trouble finding a resource online.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add these methods to your project's AppDelegate class. AppDelegate derives from KKAppDelegate which implements the UIApplicationDelegate.

Make sure to call [super method] for every method since KKAppDelegate implements basic behavior and relies on receiving some of the UIApplicationDelegate methods.

Comment: Thanks, good to know - I noticed that in the basic Kobold2d setup I'm only given the header file though? Where is the implementation stored? I mean, I know I can just ctr+cmd+up to get to it but out of curiosity, why isn't it stored with the header? Or maybe my setup is kind of buggered.

Comment: As a side note every time I see you post I feel like I'm talking to a celebrity, your cocos2d book got me into all this. Thanks :)

Comment: You're welcome! :) The AppDelegate.m should be next to AppDelegate.h. Isn't it? Maybe you accidentally dragged it into another group. In the Kobold2D templates both files are next to each other.